# List box displaying data from select box and display it as selected in php

Tags: php, ajax

I have a list box, I have select 2 items say (1 and 5) and inserted these two values in a row (inserted these two values with in single row by comma i.e. 1, 5). Now I need to display these values from database and need to display (1 and 5) as selected. But I don’t know this (because it’s inserted in a single row)

I have tried a lot, first I fetch this value and stored with an array, but it’s not working

Does anyone know?

But I don't know how

Does anyone know please help me

Comment: Have you inserted 1 and 5 in the db by comma separated?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have the value in a php variable in whole

```
$value = "1,5";
$values = explode(",",$value);
echo "<select multiple>";
// list has 10 items in example
foreach($x=1;$x<10;$x++) {
   echo "<option ";
   if (in_array($x,$values)) {
      echo "selected";
   }
   echo ">the option ".$x."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

assuming the value is a JS variable and want a javascript solution (via ajax method)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var value = "1,5";
   var d = document.getElementById("list");   // get multi-list box; change "list" name
   var values = value.split(",");
   for(var x=0,sz=d.length;x<sz;x++) {
      for(y in values) {
         if (x==values[y]) { d.options[x].selected = true; }
      }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$SQL_Item='SELECT
    CombinedColumns
    FROM
    Your_Table
    WHERE
    [Criteria];';
$RSLT_Item=mysql_query($SQL_Item);
if(mysql_num_rows($RSLT_Item)){
    $Item=mysql_fetch_assoc($RSLT_Item);
    list($Selection1, $Selection2) = explode(', ', $sqlCombinedColumns);
}
```